# How to hide "Now playing url" in control center

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, control-center

I am trying to hide livestream urls that are playing in an `UIWebView`.
When you play a livestream url and open control center (iOS) you see the url that is playing:

[image].

I would like to hide that with a HTML-based or xcode-based script.

Comment: Hey Joost. Did you ever figure this out. I am having same issue. Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control this information with the [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/index.html).  The `defaultCenter`'s `nowPlayingInfo` dictionary controls what is displayed about the current audio track on the lock screen and command center.

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *infoCenter = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];

NSDictionary *nowPlayingInfo = @{
                                 MPMediaItemPropertyTitle : @"Media Name",
                                 MPMediaItemPropertyArtist : @"Media Artist"
                                 };

[infoCenter setNowPlayingInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:nowPlayingInfo]];
```

The full list of keys are listed in the docs, but it looks like you want to set the track name to the empty string.

```
MPMediaItemPropertyTitle : @""
```